# Toggle using boolean

Tags: javascript, boolean

I am trying to style an element. I've set up a boolean and am using that to toogle between two functions. However, it won't run so I'm not sure if my script is right.

```
var dfault = false

function rand() {
        return~~ (Math.random() * 255);
    }

function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

function randFrame(){
    vid = document.getElementById("video_container");

    if(!dfault){
        vid.style.backgroundColor  = get_random_color();


    }else{
        vid.style.border = ('5px solid rgba(54,57, 62, .3)');

    }

    dfault = !dfault
}
```

Basically, I've like to change a border from it's normal color to a random color then back and forth.

HTML:

```
<div id="sideMenu">
    <ul>
        <li onclick="wideScreen()">Wide Screen</li> <!--turn sidebar on/off-->
        <li onclick="randVidframe()">Random Border</li> <!--randomize vidcontain border-->
        <li>Control Bar</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#video_container{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; 
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    border:5px solid rgba(54,57, 62, 1);
    margin: 20px;
    /*padding: 5px;*/
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    /*background-color:red;*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I believe the `var` keyword before `dfault` makes it "local", hence its value doesn't flip, if this is what you want.

Comment: Your problem is that `dfault` will always have the scope of `randVidframe()`. You need to either make the variable global or attach it to `elem` somehow.

Comment: I've removed var from the boolean, making it global. But it still won't run.

Comment: dfault is not initialized anywhere?

Comment: No, I don't think so. This is the only function i've used it in.

Comment: `elem` also does not seem to be initialized anywhere.

Comment: it's initialized in an earlier function and was global.

Comment: @Batman check that `elem` is not null - if it's assigned before the DOM is initialised then it won't work.

Comment: I've updated OP. Now working! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your script should look more like this

```
var dfault = false

function rand() {
        return~~ (Math.random() * 255);
    }
function randVidframe(){

    if(!dfault){
        elem.style.border = ('5px solid rgb(' + [rand(), rand(), rand()] + ')');

    }else{
        elem.style.border = ('5px solid rgba(54,57, 62, .3)');

    }

    dfault = !dfault
}
```

Comment: (but set dfault to true or false depending on your initial situation)

Answer (score 1):

1. local variables get reinitialised each time the function is called - you need to use a variable that's outside the function's scope, but:
2. don't use global variables, they're bad - OK?
3. ensure that your script is not called until the DOM is ready.  If you run it too soon then your elements won't be available to your script.

i.e.:

```
// don't do anything until the DOM is ready
window.onload = function() {

    // local variables
    var dfault;
    var elem = document.getElementById('myelem');

    // local function, not global
    function rand() {
        return ~~(Math.random() * 255);
    }

    // despite above warning, this function has to be global
    // because you're using DOM level 0 inline event handlers :(
    window.randVidframe = function() {
        dfault = !dfault;

        if (dfault) {  // put "true" test first
            elem.style.border = ('5px solid rgba(54,57, 62, .3)');
        } else {
            elem.style.border = ('5px solid rgb(' + [rand(), rand(), rand()] + ')');
        }
    };

    window.wideScreen = function() {
        ...
    };
};
```